# How to effectively manage memory (heap) of Android app

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am new to android, could any one please tell me how to write effective code with respect to memory management.

```
public class XXX extends Activity  {

EditText et;
ImageView iv;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
iv  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);


}

     public void release(){
 et=null;

 Drawable drawable = ((ImageView) iv).getDrawable();
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().recycle();
        }

 iv=null;
System.gc();
}

 public void onPic(View v){
// code to capture image
 }

public void onSave(View v){
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    SqliteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

String name =   et.getText().toString();

ContentValues cv cv= new ContentValues();
// saving , calling release();  and going back to main screen


}
```

Is there any thing i could do to avoid out of memory, hanging phone?

Comment: while displaying the images in image view you can always resize the image to the needed size and then set to avoid out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap do not easily releases the memory due to which mostly the out of memory exception is caused. You can resize the bitmap and load it.

This might help you which shows efficient bitmap loading:
[Bitmap loading](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

You can go through complete understanding document from here
[Bitmap handling](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)